# How to get value from time picker?

Tags: c#, ajax

I am using a third part time picker. The time picker assembly is

```
<%@ Register Assembly="TimePicker" Namespace="MKB.TimePicker" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

the source code behind the time picker is

```
<tr>
    <td align="left" class="style3">
        From Time
    </td>
    <td align="left">
        <cc1:TimeSelector ID="TimeSelector1" runat="server" Height="10px">
        </cc1:TimeSelector>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to add the selected time into database. How can I set the selected time into a string or how can I retrieve the selected time? I just tried to gain the value like

```
string time=TimeSelector1.SelectedTimeFormat.ToString()
```

but it's not working. I have a class named master there I did like this:

```
mas.leaveapply(ddcode.SelectedItem.Text, 
               txtname.Text, 
               TimeSelector1.SelectedTimeFormat.ToString());
```

Comment: have you read the documentation for the TimePicker?

Comment: I'd check `TimeSelector` properties, (`SelectedTimeFormat` is format, not value).

Comment: Adriano Repetti, how can we retrive the value?

Comment: why my reputation getting deducted?

Comment: Can I answer with a quote? _"Rhumborl, Nope i didnt read"_. Good, do it. About reputation: because you first should (AT LEAST) read documentation, SO users aren't here to do it for you.

Comment: @DwaneMarsh, if you didn't read it the I suggest you do, the website is here and it explains exactly how top do what you need. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/TimePicker-control-in-ASPNet-with-example.aspx

Comment: @Ben Robinson, I read the article but i did not get the idea how to pass selected data through parameters

Comment: @DwaneMarsh see the section entitled "Fetching Time Value from TimePicker on PostBack", it seems you need to access various properties such as `TimeSelecter1.Hours` to get the hours part of the time.

Comment: @Ben Robinson, Thank you with your instruction I got the expected output..

Comment: please provide formatted code next time.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the above question is

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {


            DateTime time1 = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", TimeSelector1.Hour, TimeSelector1.Minute,TimeSelector1.AmPm));
            DateTime time2 = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", TimeSelector2.Hour, TimeSelector2.Minute, TimeSelector2.AmPm));


            mas.leaveapply(time1.ToShortTimeString(),time2.ToShortTimeString());
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You Have Succesfully Applied For Leave ..!!');", true);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

It shows time like "10:05 PM/AM"(Hour,Minute,AM/PM)

Answer (score 0):

**Create a method like below:**

```
 public static string SetDBTime(MKB.TimePicker.TimeSelector TimeSelector1)
        {
            string time = TimeSelector1.Hour+":"+TimeSelector1.Minute+" "+TimeSelector1.AmPm;
            return time;
        }
```

**Then call the function:**

```
string TimeData = DateTime.Parse(SetDBTime(name_of_your_time_selector)).ToString("HH:mm");
```